# Tax deductible travel and lodging expenses

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction

I'm wondering if travel and lodging expenses are tax deductible in the following situation: I live with my family in city A (in California). I have a full-time job in city B (also in California). The distance between city A and city B is 500 miles.

During the week I rent a room in city B that's very close to the office. Each weekend I fly to city A, see my family, and fly back to city B for work the next week.

The lodging and travel expenses are really adding up! Since these costs are for the explicit purpose of working at my full-time, salaried job, can I deduct them in any way from my taxes?

Any advice is helpful! My accountant is busy with tax season, so I don't want to bother her now.

Comment: Actually, you unambiguously live in city B and commute to city A to visit your family. This should make clear why your travel and lodging is not tax-deductible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot. Commute to the office is not a deductible expense. *Moving* from A to B would be deductible, had you moved for the job.